# How to export video from Photos.app with original Created Date (macOS: 13.5.1)?

Tags: photos, photos.app, video

The export with the original Created date works well on images, but when I export videos from the Photos.app even with the option **Export Unmodified Original for ...** from the **File** menu the video has the date and time when export is finished.

Please, how is it possible to retain the original date while exporting multiple videos?